# Colors changing when artboard duplicated in illlustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, artboard

Having a little issue here that has me completely stumped.  Whenever I duplicate an artboart, it changes the colors slightly.  I Here is how it looks.  [image]

You can see that the artboard on the left is a shade of grey, whereas the one on the right is slightly bluer.  What gives?  What am I missing?  Thank you so much in advance! Any ideas much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

They are the same.

It's an optical illusion due to the gradient and the UI coloring.... Which is why I stick to the Light UI coloring.

[image]

That's the right side overlaid on the left side.. there's no edge showing any color variation.

When you are uncertain about this, it's a simple matter to select the object and check the **Color Panel** for the *numbers* used. If they are the same... it's an illusion. You can also use the **Info Panel** to just hover your cursor over various areas and see the *numbers* related to the color breakout to verify they are the same.

Comment: Well I took the photo into photoshop.  The background colors appear to be different.  Right one seems more saturated than the left.

Comment: "Seems more" is not very definitive. And well.. that's kind of the definition of "illusion" isn't it? for something to "seem" different when it actually isn't. :) Open the info panel... hover your cursor over different areas.. read the numbers.. they are the same (at least here based on the posted screenshot).

Comment: Color on the right is f1fdf  and the color on the left is f6f8f8.

Comment: Interesting.. since the info panel doesn't provide hex colors and using the eyedropper can **average** a color over several pixels and requires clicking the **exact** same location for both sides. Clearly you refuse to believe me.. so good luck! I don't know what else to tell you.